# how to start a service properly and keep it alive?

Tags: android, service

I know there are other question with the same topic, but I didn't find an answer to my questions.

my goal is to have a service which works on the background as a location listener, and it won't be stopped when the application is stopped (either by a task killer).

currently, I'm starting the service with startService(Intent) if it the service isn't started already and bind to it using bindService(Intent,ServiceConnection, 0).

now, the first problem is that my application crashes but the service has started, and when I run the application again it works.

the second problem, is that if I kill my application using advanced task killer, it kills my service as well, although in the Service page it says that the service will be stopped when no bounded clients left and if  stopService() or stopSelf() have been called.

Comment: ok, I found out why it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

> and it won't be stopped when the application is stopped (either by a task killer).

Fortunately, this is not possible. If your user wishes your service to stop, the user can stop the service via a task killer or the Manage Services screen in Settings.

> currently, I'm starting the service with startService(Intent) if it the service isn't started already and bind to it using bindService(Intent,ServiceConnection, 0).

Usually, you only use one or the other, not both.

> the second problem, is that if I kill my application using advanced task killer, it kills my service as well, although in the Service page it says that the service will be stopped when no bounded clients left and if stopService() or stopSelf() have been called.

No, because you called `startService()` in addition to `bindService()`.

Comment: well it seems that in android 2.2 it works just fine.

killing the the app that started the service didn't kill the service.

I'm assuming its because starting with api 5, onStartCommand is called and not onStart.

BTW, Why is my android SDK doesn't include api 5 and 6?

Answer (score 0):

The service stops when the application is closed by the task manager. If this could not be possible every app would have its own service running without any user control over them. You could start the service at boot up and then when the user uses task manager to close, you could restart the service.

Comment: but when I kill the app, onDestroy isn't called

Comment: How do you know onDestroy() is not called?

Comment: If you have a System.out to print something then move it above the `super.onDestroy();`. The system clears everything and the code below super.onDestroy() is not executed

Comment: I have a Log.i and I moved it before super.onDestroy() and it still didn't log it.

Comment: how Gmail, Yahoo etc.. get notified when a task killer gets them killed? I mean in android 1.5.