# How to combine two applications into one

Tags: android, service

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913960/how-to-start-a-service-properly-and-keep-it-alive), I found out that using BroadcastReceiver to launch my service, the service launches on startup and it doesn't show on task killer.

now my question is, how I add this application (or package) to my main application, so it will be installed as two applications.

I tried to add it as a library, but then the service is attached to the main app, and it can be killed with task killer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuses me. Perhaps it is because on the Android, the words 'activity', 'application', 'service' etc take on different meanings from what they would be on another platform. Perhaps you can describe better e.g.

What icons do you want to see on your app launcher?
What entries do you want to see in your app manager > installed apps?

another thing i didn't understand is "how to add this app/pkg to your main application, so that it will be installed as two apps". If you add a package to your main application, then there will only be one application.

Comment: my situation is as follows: I have a main app that uses a service (location listener in short). now I need it to be two different apps because when they are one, before android 2.2 (or 2.0), if I kill the app it kills the service. I don't intent to make something that can't be killed, but I need to separate the service from the app

Comment: you can contain a service within an application WITHOUT an activity.

Comment: you can try to separate your 3 parts into 3 separate applications. your service being 1 application, and the other 2 applications which you call from.